# Grouping transactions description and count in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame that contains transactions. I would like to group similar transactions together and count the occurrence of those transactions for a single customer in python.
The data looks like this:

```
account   transaction_date  transaction description   transaction_amt
55625       15/may/19          POS: McDonalds             $15
55625       01/may/19          Netflix                    $31.5
55625       28/may/19          POS:H&M                    $150
55625       6/apr/19           Netflix                    $9
55625       30/may             McDonalds                  $6
55625       25/may/19          POS:H&M                    $32
55625       6/mar/19           POS:H&M                    $32
```

I want the data to be grouped in such a way that it counts the number of times the shops were visited in a month and the total spent 
It should look like this:

```
account   trans_date  trans_description   total_spent    
55625       may/19        McDonalds          $21
55625       may/19           H&M             $182
55625       mar/19           H&M             $32
55625       may/19          Netflix          $31.5
55625       apr/19          Netflix          $9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First process column with datetimes, remove values before `:` in `description` columns and remove `$` from `transaction_amt` and convert to numeric:

```
df['transaction_date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['transaction_date'], 
                                        format='%d/%b/%y', errors='coerce')
                            .dt.strftime('%b/%y'))
df['transaction description'] = df['transaction description'].str.split(':').str[-1]
df['transaction_amt'] = df['transaction_amt'].str.lstrip('$').astype(float)
print (df)

   account transaction_date transaction description  transaction_amt
0    55625           May/19               McDonalds             15.0
1    55625           May/19                 Netflix             31.5
2    55625           May/19                     H&M            150.0
3    55625           Apr/19                 Netflix              9.0
4    55625              NaT               McDonalds              6.0
5    55625           May/19                     H&M             32.0
6    55625           Mar/19                     H&M             32.0
```

Then aggregate sum:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['account','transaction_date','transaction description'])['transaction_amt']
         .sum()
         .reset_index(name='total_spent'))
print (df1)
   account transaction_date transaction description  total_spent
0    55625           Apr/19                 Netflix          9.0
1    55625           Mar/19                     H&M         32.0
2    55625           May/19                     H&M        182.0
3    55625           May/19               McDonalds         15.0
4    55625           May/19                 Netflix         31.5
5    55625              NaT               McDonalds          6.0
```

If in input data is always year in datetime column solution is:

```
print (df)
   account transaction_date transaction description transaction_amt
0    55625        15/may/19           POS:McDonalds             $15
1    55625        01/may/19                 Netflix           $31.5
2    55625        28/may/19                 POS:H&M            $150
3    55625         6/apr/19                 Netflix              $9
4    55625        30/may/19               McDonalds              $6
5    55625        25/may/19                 POS:H&M             $32
6    55625         6/mar/19                 POS:H&M             $32


df['transaction_date'] = df['transaction_date'].str.split('/', n=1).str[1]
df['transaction description'] = df['transaction description'].str.split(':').str[-1]
df['transaction_amt'] = df['transaction_amt'].str.lstrip('$').astype(float)
print (df)
   account transaction_date transaction description  transaction_amt
0    55625           may/19               McDonalds             15.0
1    55625           may/19                 Netflix             31.5
2    55625           may/19                     H&M            150.0
3    55625           apr/19                 Netflix              9.0
4    55625           may/19               McDonalds              6.0
5    55625           may/19                     H&M             32.0
6    55625           mar/19                     H&M             32.0

df1 = (df.groupby(['account','transaction_date','transaction description'])['transaction_amt']
         .sum()
         .reset_index(name='total_spent'))
print (df1)
   account transaction_date transaction description  total_spent
0    55625           apr/19                 Netflix          9.0
1    55625           mar/19                     H&M         32.0
2    55625           may/19                     H&M        182.0
3    55625           may/19               McDonalds         21.0
4    55625           may/19                 Netflix         31.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `df.groupby()` ?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

It works similarly to SQL's group by if you're familiar with that one.

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to convert transaction_date(dd/mmm/yy) to trans_date(mmm/yy). You can use datetime library or dateutil library. Then create a new column trans_description from transaction_description by removing unwanted words like **"POS:"**

Then you can just use `groupby()` function in pandas library. Group by (date and description columns)
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html